# Linux multiple FIND statements and IF condition / /bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a script that checks if there in no specific Files that has parameter in the name on any position, and after statement is true (there is no such file), function should create directory with same name as Parameter $1, move files from symlink Current to newly created directory, and after that find and remove all files that are not in /current/ and contains in name @tp or numbers. I've wrote something like this, but don't know why, it's not working, can I get any help? :)

```
   if[-ne $1]; then mkdir $1 && mv /current/* data/data2/data3/$1 

        find /home/ -not -path /current/ -and -not -newer /current/ -and -name *@tmp" -exec rm -r {} \; -name "*[0-9]*" -exec rm -r {} \;

        else

        echo "There is this tag already "

        fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for non-existing directory, you can use this:

```
if [ ! -d $1 ]
```

instead of

```
if [ -ne $1 ]
```

**Update**: the previous command will only look for matching folder name. If you want to search for folders containing your parameter, you could use something like this:

```
if [[ `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*${1}*"` = "" ]]; then
       # ... commands when your param is not part of any dir ...
fi
```

Comment: Note the spaces around the `[` and `]`, and probably better to quote `"$1"`.

Comment: Another thing, if ! -d $1 will check If file contains parameter on any position or only if files has the same name as parameter?

Comment: And how about rest of script, does it look legit? Thank you for understanding :)